# adding css class in <body> javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing an issue in jquery , i want to add a css `test` class in body tag.

My code

```
(function($) {  

    if($("#root").length){
        $("#root").closest("body").addClass('co_queue_page'); //not working
    }

})(jQuery);
```

```
<div class="row">    //react code
 <div id="root">
  <div> 
   <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">...</div>
   </header>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

what should i do? some help me help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You code is working just fine for me

Comment: where is the body tag ?

Comment: yes body tag is mention [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10351377/rishu-ranjan)

Comment: @RishuRanjan While the `body` tag is missing from the code provided from the op, I believe that it exist in the op's solution

Comment: yes `body` tag is exist [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943218/carsten-l%c3%b8vbo-andersen)

Comment: i am doing this work in react app [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10351377/rishu-ranjan)

Comment: Just use $('body').addClass('co_queue_page'), with required condition.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.closest()` method, there is only one  tag in HTML document, just do it by selecting the `<body>` directly:

```js
(function($) {  

    if($("#root").length){
        $("body").addClass('co_queue_page');
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i try , but it is not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896358/root)

Comment: can you reproduce it here in a snippet, if possible add the HTML and how you are adding  the javascript to the document.

Comment: i have added screeenshot [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896358/root)

Comment: seems to me that the if statement is not entered, what happen if you add it using `setTimeout()`? **this is not a good solution but can lead you to what the issue is**, let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

To select the `<body>` element, using jQuery, you can use:

```
const element = $(document.body);
const element = $("body");
```

Then you can use `.addClass()` to add your custom class dynamically, like so:

```
element.addClass("co_queue_page");
```

[jQuery fiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/derg417v/)

This can be also done without any jQuery, accessing the body DOM element through the document object:

```
const element = document.body;
element.classList.add("co_queue_page");
```

[Vanilla JS fiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/m0pxu19L/)

Comment: thanks , i try but it is not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8043571/gdevdeiv)

Comment: I just added two jsFiddle links, so you can test it yourself :)

Comment: thanks , i try but it is not working in jquery [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8043571/gdevdeiv)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code:

```
$("body").addClass("class_name");
```